# DNS problem when creating VM from deprovisioned Linux VM image in DevTest Lab

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-devtest-labs

I tried many times.  It looks like a bug in Azure DevTest Labs.

Here is the steps to reproduce the problem:

1. Create a VM from Ubuntu Linux 18.04 LTS
2. Create custom image from this VM with **Run deprovision on virtual machine.**.
3. Create a new VM from this new image.
4. SSH to this VM.
5. Run `host www.google.com` will fail.

Are these steps wrong?

Comment: If the answer is helpful you can accept it for other people who look for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no step wrong which you have done. But the reason that you fail running `host www.google.com` is the second step. The deprovision will do some things when you execute the command `waagent -deprovision+user`:

[image]

When you create a VM from the deprovision custom image, there is no resolv.conf file in it. So you fail in running `host www.google.com`. The solution is that create a resolv.conf file in the directory `/etc/`.

The content of file resolv.conf will be different for the VM in the different locations. For example, the file resolv.conf will be like this if your VM in the location Japan East:

```
nameserver 127.0.0.53
search bbuuanmggeiengfg01a443drie.lx.internal.cloudapp.net
```

Comment: Is it normal?  I mean when I create a VM from the custom image.  Why should everyone restore `resolv.conf` by himself?  Is it possible to reconfigure DNS automatically when creating VMs from deprovisioned custom image?

Comment: @WillHuang This is an issue about "walinuxagent", you can read this [link](https://github.com/Azure/WALinuxAgent/issues/1151) and find the way to solve it.

Comment: Is this issue going to be fixed? I saw the issue has been closed but the workaround still remain.  Or it will leave it as a workaround forever?

Comment: Yeah, I also see that. But with the test of version 2.2.31, the error still exists. So you should fix it in another way. Maybe it would be fixed later.